# Extract text from given area with pypdf

Tags: pypdf

is it possible to extract a text from a given area without the need to save and reload the file?

For example:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def crop(page, top, left, width, height):
    page.cropbox.upper_left = (top,left)
    page.cropbox.lower_right = (width,height)
    return page
    
with open (file_path, 'rb') as pdfFileObj:
    pdfReader = PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    tot_pages = pdfReader.numPages
    print(tot_pages)
    for page in range(int(tot_pages/2)):
        month_box = crop(pdfReader.pages[page], 1000,170,1280,210)
        print(month_box.extractText())
```

EDIT: Now I am using tabula-py, the extraction using x and y coordinates is very simple

Answer (score 1):

You can use visitor functions:

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("GeoTopo.pdf")
page = reader.pages[1]


parts = []


def visitor_body(text, cm, tm, fontDict, fontSize):
    y = tm[5]
    if y > 150 and y < 200:
        parts.append(text)


page.extract_text(visitor_text=visitor_body)
text_body = "".join(parts)
print(text_body)
```

However, it only works properly with the y-coordinate. It doesn't work well with the x coordinate.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I need mostly the x-coordinate. I will find another way like tabula